# PHP Swig Example

Tags: php, swig

I've been trying to get a dynamically created extension for PHP using Swig working and I can't figure out how to get there example to work.  From their site:

```
/* File : example.c */

double  My_variable  = 3.0;

/* Compute factorial of n */
int  fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return n*fact(n-1);
}

/* Compute n mod m */
int my_mod(int n, int m) {
    return(n % m);
}

/* File : example.i */
%module example
%{
/* Put headers and other declarations here */
extern double My_variable;
extern int    fact(int);
extern int    my_mod(int n, int m);
%}

extern double My_variable;
extern int    fact(int);
extern int    my_mod(int n, int m);

swig -php example.i
gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c example_wrap.c
gcc -shared example_wrap.o -o example.so
[php.ini]
extension=/path/to/modulename.so
```

Everything works as expected but I cannot get the module to load into PHP.  Keep getting the following error:

undefined symbol: My_variable in /var/www/html/test/time.php on line 11

I can't figure out what to do to get it to work, nor have I been able to find working examples anywhere on the internet.  Any pointers or examples of how to get Swig to work would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the INI file you should have

```
extension=/path/to/example.so
```

However, this will load your extension for every PHP script, regardless of whether or not the script uses your extension. You should probably use

```
include("example.php");
```

I don't know PHP much but based on the PHP section of SWIG docs my guess is that global variables like `My_variable` are accessed via `_get()` and `_set()` function calls. For example:

```
include("example.php");
print My_variable_get();
My_variable_set( My_variable_get() * 2 );
print My_variable_get(); # prints 6
```

That might have been the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

In the compilation step you have missed the source file which contains definition for global My_Varible, function fact(), and function my_mode(). So the first step of compilation should be

```
gcc `php-config --includes` -fpic -c example_wrap.c example.c
```

followed by linking step as

```
gcc -shared example_wrap.o example.o -o example.so
```

**You were getting the variable not found error because your library did not include the actual definition of the variables, it only had declaration.**

Comment: Also because the official documentation is wrong! ( https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html#Php_nn1_1 ) Thank you very much :) . (and it's fixed on GitHub/master branch already)

Answer (score 0):

use lowercase for export names (My_variable ==> my_variable)